# Travis cannot find my .travis.yaml file

Tags: travis-ci

Whenever I push a new commit, Travis CI fails my build with this message at the top of every log:

> WARNING: We were unable to find a .travis.yml file. This may not be
>   what you want. Build will be run with default settings.
>
> Using worker:
>   worker-linux-docker-71483f98.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-6
>
> Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration.

However, I definitely have a .travis.yaml file in the root of my repository.  Here are its contents:

```
$ cat .travis.yaml 
language:
  node_js

node_js:
  stable

script:
  node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
```

Some people seem to have encountered similar issues because they renamed their repositories, but I have never changed the name of this repository.  Others say it just fixed itself after a couple hours, but it has been 5 days for me and nothing has changed.

Nothing in the Travis CI documentation seems to indicate that I need to do anything more than sync my repos, active the repo I want CI for, and include a .travis.yaml file in the repo.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong extension for your YAML file.

It needs to be `.travis.yml` not `.travis.yaml`.

Comment: That did it.  I'm surprised it doesn't support the longer extension.  Thanks!